# Can't use local file images in Next 12

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js

Created a new project in Next js with Next version 12.

Whenever I try to import and use an image file in the `/public` directory I get a build failure.

```
../public/images/header-logo.jpg
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5575:34)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5901:42
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:202:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

The image is in the `public` directory, I have no next.config.js file.

This error is only thrown during a build. If I import the image file no error is thrown.

If I use it as the `src` property in a `next/image` component, then the build error is thrown.

Comment: How are you setting your `src` property?

Comment: remove public like this:  /images/header-logo.jpg

Comment: @H9ee that's a file path not a URL. https://i.imgur.com/qjCeYAu.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After losing 4 hours of my life, it turns out the issue was the experimental version of Node I installed.

Downgrading to version 16 fixed this issue.

Comment: I was using the Node v18.0.0 and got the same error. Upgrading to 18.18.1 resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

Images should not be requested nor imported. To use images you should just use the path /images/header-logo.jpg

or

```
<Image src="/images/header-logo.jpg" width=xxx height=xxx />
```

Comment: Thank you, but my Next 9 project does this just fine and I really like using the StaticImageData object. So while this doesn't break my project, I would very much like it to work.